# Please unprotect Largest Number Printable

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, specific-question, protected-questions

Please unprotect [Largest Number Printable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18028/79782) so [my answer may be considered](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/12647#comment81117_12647) and create discussion.

Comment: I'm closing this question because 1. this is not an appropriate use of meta, 2. the linked question is not closed, 3. the linked answer is neither yours nor a main site answer, and 4. the premise of this post doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino I believe the OP is talking about the code posted as a comment on that sandbox answer. I believe they want to answer that question, but can't because it hasn't been posted, and it hasn't been posted because it *would be* closed.

Comment: @WheatWizard Oh, I guess that would make sense. I figured they probably meant unprotect instead of open but I didn't think to check the comments considering you can link comments themselves. Does that post need to be protected? It was last protected by the bot but I don't know if we deliberately left it protected or if we can revert that (also, I thought we disabled that, but I might have misremembered).

Comment: Yes @hyper-neutrino I scrolled to the bottom of the [linked question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18028/79782) there is nowhere to answer, maybe it is just protected from answers? What is meta for in every other stack? My answer is in the comments of the second linked question there was no shortcut to link to comments. Sometimes things don't make sense we shouldn't feel bad.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Probably I can link to a comment from the time on the desktop but not on my phone.

Comment: Makes sense. The reason I said it isn't appropriate is only because I didn't understand what you were trying to do. You asked us to reopen a post that wasn't closed to consider an answer that I couldn't find. I get what you mean now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For the moment, the question will stay protected

[Questions are protected](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) when they receive a large number of low quality answers, especially by new users, that get downvoted and deleted. [Largest Number Printable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18028/66833) is a *prime* example for this - it has 49 deleted answers, 36 of which are negatively scored, and a quick scan shows that multiple were posted by users with less than 50 reputation on the site.

If you are absolutely certain that your answer deserves to be posted to this challenge, then there's an easy way to do this: earn 10 reputation. Post an answer and challenge that receives 1 upvotes, and you'll be able to answer Largest Number Printable (and all other protected questions). The point of protection is to prevent answers being posted by anonymous and very-low reputation users, specifically in the cases where the record is not in their favor.

Also, when posting new answers to questions with so many answers (93 undeleted at time of writing), you should really ask yourself if your answer provides any new approach. From the program in the linked comment in your question, I doubt it does: it's just exponenting a large number. The existing answers are already unimaginably many orders of magnitude greater than that.

Comment: I would rather search for prime number in 256 char or less with no input since the question allows multiple outputs scoring only the largest number but I doubt I will manage before I finish working on this https://github.com/Willtech/Prime/tree/working